# Incompatible type error when calling a function

Tags: arrays, pascal, delphi-2007, delphi

I have two functions which are dynamic arrays. one is a function used to split strings and the other is where the function is being called. I am getting an error at on this line of code `tempArr := SplitString(line);` Below is my exact code:

```
 type
    TArrayStr = array Of string;

function SplitString(stringToSplit: string):  TArrayStr;
    var
   intIdx: Integer;
   intIdxOutput: Integer;
const
   Delimiter = ';';      // made the delimeter a constant
begin
//set the length of the single dimension array
   intIdxOutput := 0;
   SetLength(Result, 1);
   Result[0] := '';
   //furnish this array
   for intIdx := 1 to Length(stringTosplit) do
   begin
      if stringTosplit[intIdx] = Delimiter then
      begin
        intIdxOutput := intIdxOutput + 1;
         SetLength(Result, Length(Result));     // set the length of the dynamic array
      end
      else
         Result[intIdxOutput] := Result[intIdxOutput] + stringTosplit[intIdx];
   end;
end;

type
TDoubleDynArray = array of double;

function ReadColumn(filename: string; colNumber: integer):TDoubleDynArray;
var
  myFile: TextFile;
  line: String;
  tempArr: array of double;
  colValue: double;
  colArray: array of double;
  i: integer;
  j: integer;
  edtcolumnNo: Tedit;
//  colNumber: int;

begin
  // Open the text file for reading
  AssignFile(myFile, filename);
  Reset(myfile);

  // Skip the header lines
  while not Eof(myFile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(myFile, line);
    if AnsiStartsStr('chapters', line) then Break;
  end;

  // Read each line, but keep only the desired column
  j := 0;
  while not Eof(myFile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(myFile, line);
    tempArr := SplitString(line); // this is the problem

    // go through array
      colNumber := strToint(edtcolumnNo.text);
    colValue :=  tempArr[colNumber];
    colArray[j] := colValue;
    j := j + 1;
  end;
  close(myFile);
  result := colArray;
end;
```

for the line `tempArr` is a array of double while `SplitString(line)` is a array of string. i have tried converting string to float but error persisted with overload. not too sure what to do at this point. Could anyone please help as to what i might be doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: You can't assign an array of string to an array of double. I mean, you can't assign a string to a double. Make the variable on the lhs match the type of the rhs.

Comment: yes i tried doing that by converting the string on the rhs to a double. I might be wrong with my approach has I tried using the `strTofloat` function to convert. is there any other ways to deal with this dynamic arrays? The exact error i get is `incompatible types: dynamic array and TArraystr.`  Thanks

Comment: Make the variable on the lhs match the type of the rhs. Then convert once you have the array of strings.

Comment: As David says, just make tempArr a TArrayString. There is no reason to make it an array of double, as far as I can tell. Then use something like colValue := StrToFloat(tempArr[colNumber]);

Comment: @Nadia I have a feeling there might be a general flaw in your design. Could you please share us more infomation of what you are trying to achieve and perhaps show an example of your imput file. Unfortunately based on currently available information we can't even guess what you are trying to do and thus we haave no idea why in one function you are operating with strings and in other iwth double values

Comment: thanks @RudyVelthuis that worked thanks alot guys

Comment: @silverwarrior , yes i might be having a whole bunch of other problems now